# Why PHP GD library fails to write images on my disk?

Tags: php, gd

I wrote a piece of php (test.php) code like this

```
$width = 300;
$height = 200;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
$mypic = imagecolorallocate($im,100,30,125);
imagefill($im,0,0,$mypic);
imagepng($im,'./mypic.png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

When I run it on Ubuntu command line (php test.php), it works fine and writes mypic.png on my disk. However, when I access test.php on remote client (Chrome), it shows the picture correctly, but the program fails to write images on my disk.

Comment: Check for write permissions.

Comment: you can also check to see if any error messages are being thrown, it should give you a clue where it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` assuming /var/www/ is your site directory. Or make the file  you are writing to have write permissions.

Comment: Problem is solved. My apache is started by root, and when there is a http request, the corresponding user is www-data, not root. Right?